# Process does not run in background as intended

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, background-process

My simple shell program gets an array of commands as an input, if `&` is at the end of the array, the child process should run in the background and the parent should not wait for child to finish.
However when I compile and run my code, I insert commands without `&` and with `&` and they all run in the backgroud. I tried to test it with entering `sleep 50s` as input.

```
int process_arglist(int count, char** arglist){
signal(SIGCHLD,SIG_IGN);
int pid = fork();
int flag=0; //turned to 1 in case there's a & or |

if(pid <0){ //check if fork failed
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fork failed\n");
    return 1;
}

if(pid == 0){ // Child's proccess
    //check last arglist argument
    if (strcmp(arglist[count - 1], "&") == 0) {
        flag=1;
        setpgid(0, 0);
        arglist[count - 1] = NULL;
        if (execvp(*arglist, arglist) < 0) {     //execute the command
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: execvp failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    if(flag==0){ //There is no &
        if (execvp(*arglist, arglist) < 0) {     //execute the command
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: execvp failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    }
if(pid > 0){ //Parent's process
    return 1;
}

    return 0;

}
```

Any ideas how to make only the input with `&` at the end run in the background?

Comment: quick & dirty: don't use `fork` + `exec` in the "foreground" case. use `system` which blocks until command is finished.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  what do you mean by system? I don't want to block, I want the two processes to run

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Better use `popen()`.